# Plotting lat/lon points on Apple Maps vs Google Maps

Tags: ios6-maps

I'm using Google Places to get latitude and longitude for places near a user, and then plotting those points on both Apple Maps (on iOS 6, using MKMapView) and plotting them on Google Maps (using Javascript V3).  Now the problem is when I plot them on MKMapView the points are not in their correct positions, while on Google Maps they are.  Why is this the case?  Shouldn't plotting a latitude/longitude point on a map make it have the same point?

Comment: Show the code you are using for both maps or some sample coordinates where you see a difference.

Comment: Thanks I got it working, was just parsing the xml file incorrectly and gettings points incorrect :)

Answer (score 0):

The points are the same. However The image overlays are going to be different. This could be due to the angles that the images where taken at, an we all know that Apple is having some small issues fixing there mapping program. I hope this helps.